# Supress notifications sound and vibration with NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm currently using `NotificationListenerService` to cancel notifications, and it's working fine.

I want to know if I can supress their sound and vibration, like when the phone is in `INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALARMS` filter, making the notification only be shown, but make no noise at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately from what I know, I believe the answer is "no".

NotificationListenerService is just a listener.  Android posts the notification and then notifies the NotificationListenerService.  It seems not possible to intercept notifications.  At least not this way.